# 2way data binding VDataTable Vue + JSX

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, jsx

I have a VDataTable in vue + jsx, and i need a simple 2-way data binding with the props `sortBy` and `sortDesc`.

So basically i need the equivalent to

```
 <template>
  <v-data-table
    :items="desserts"
    :sort-desc="sortDesc"
    :sort-by="sortBy"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>
```

for me it made sense to put set those attributes as `data` (the items of the table is a computed property):

```
  data() {
    return {
      sortDesc: false,
      sortBy: "someFieldName"
    };
  },
```

The data table itself looks like this:

```
  <VDataTable
    items={this.desserts}
    sortBy={this.sortBy}
    sortDesc={this.sortDesc}
   />
```

When mounted, the data table is rendered correctly with the given sortBy and sortDesc values, but the data does not change when clicking on the header of the table. I have also tried to change the data manually in an update event, but i can't get behind on how `update:sort-by` gets translated into jsx.

I am quite new to jsx, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out to use the `on` prop with field `update:sort-by` :

```
 <VDataTable
    items={this.desserts}
    sortBy={this.sortBy}
    sortDesc={this.sortDesc}
    on={{'update:sort-by':this.updateSort}}
   />
```